# Списки С++. Конвертирование собственных типов класса

Tags: c++, списки

имеется код:

```
class TElement
{
public:
 TElement *next,*prev;
};
class TSpisok
{
 TElement *first,*last,*cur;
public:
   TSpisok() {
    first = last = cur = NULL;
   };
   void ShowList (int index)
   {
        cur = first;
        while (cur != NULL) {
        Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(cur); //здесь возникает ошибка из-за несоответствия типов
        }

   };
};
class TNumber :  public TElement {
    public: int num;
    TNumber(int n): TElement(),
    num(n) {}
};

class TString :  public TElement {
    public: char str[20];
    TString(char s[20]): TElement() {
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
};
TElement * p;
TSpisok Spisok;

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
char * st;
int k;
st = new char[20];
st = Edit1->Text.c_str();
if (strstr(st, "") != NULL) {
            k = atoi(st);
            if (k || (strlen(st) == 1 && st[0] == '0')) {
                    p = new TNumber(k);
                    Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(k);
                    } else
                    {
                    p = new TString(st);
                    Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(st);
                    }
                    Spisok.AddElement(p);
        }

}
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
if (RadioGroup1->ItemIndex == 0)
Spisok.ShowList(0); else
Spisok.ShowList(1);
}
```

Мне нужно по нажатию 2ой кнопки на форме вывести элементы списка на ListBox, но я не могу этого из за ошибки. Как правильно вернуть элемент списка на форму?

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(65): E2034 Cannot convert 'TElement *' to 'AnsiString'

Comment: Вам компилятор прямо говорит, что он не знает как конвертировать указатель на ваш тип `TElement` к строке. И при чем сдесь абстрактные классы и приведение типов?

Comment: Я не очень силен в программировании (совсем не силен), по этому так сформулировал тему. Если компилятор не знает как конвертировать, тогда я могу указать ему явное преобразование в  (char)cur? Или как это нужно сделать? :(

Comment: нет, это не поможет, так как вам следовало бы знать, что во-первых: ваш класс наследуется не от `char *`, во-вторых, при наследовании в начало объекта помещается таблица функций, так что вы не можете просто взять указатель на класс и преобразовать его в `char *` (точнее можете, точно так же как можете выстрелить себе в ногу)